# How to animate line graph in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a project that I'm working on that was inspired by the [Amazing NYTimes Interactive Charts](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/01/15/us/politics/you-draw-obama-legacy.html) where you would draw the chart and see how you did compared to real data. I want to make a simple version of that using D3.

[Here is my working codepen so far](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKjobZ)

It is rough but it works.

What I want to do, however, is to have the line be 'drawn' across the graph once the user clicks 'How did I do?'

[This is a great example of what I'm after with the second line](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326)

I followed the above example and added a transition to the javascript like so.

```
function addSecondLine(){
    focus.append("path")
        .datum(morePoints)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "green")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line)
        .transition()
        .duration(4000);
}
```

But that didn't achieve anything.

Comment: I don't think the codepen screenshot is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

https://codepen.io/shreya0712/pen/ZEYYrMd?editors=1010

I hope this is what you'd been trying.

```
    function addSecondLine() {
      var line2 = focus
        .append("path")
        .datum(morePoints)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "green")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line);

      var totalLength = line2.node().getTotalLength();

      line2
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This effect is done using the `stroke-dashoffset` property. Right now in your code, you're making a transition toward nothing.

First you need to set the offset to the total length of your path, then you'll need to make a transition to an offset of 0.

This is clear in the example you provided.

```
path
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Comment: So I'm a bit confused. I've modified my codepen with your example and don't see the effect. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKjobZ

Comment: The `totalLength` is a variable, you need to set it to be equal to the length of the path. In the example you provided, it is set like this `var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();`

Comment: I just can't get this to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.